# How to display intersection labels in seaborn graph?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

Want to display the name of each datapoint in the graph.
Aim was to get a single graph which shows the information for all countries. X axis shows the number of hospitals and y axis shows the number of MRI. I'm getting the graph but how to get the name of each country displayed next to their respective datapoint.

Here is my code.

```
dfn = ['Australia', 'Belgium', 'Canada', 'Denmark']
dfx = [2,4,6,3]
dfy = [3,2,8,1]
sns.regplot(x=dfx, y=dfy, fit_reg=False)
plt.scatter
plt.xlabel('Hospitals')
plt.ylabel('MRIs')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop with [pyplot.text](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) to add each label:

```
import seaborn as sns
dfn = ['Australia', 'Belgium', 'Canada', 'Denmark']
dfx = [2,4,6,3]
dfy = [3,2,8,1]
sns.regplot(x=dfx, y=dfy, fit_reg=False)
plt.scatter
plt.xlabel('Hospitals')
plt.ylabel('MRIs')
for i in range(len(dfn)):
    plt.text(dfx[i]+0.1,dfy[i]+0.1,dfn[i])
```

[image]

And maybe change the limits of the plot to include the labels, for example:

```
plt.xlim((1.5,7))
plt.ylim((0.5,8.5))
```

Comment: Thank you for this smart and simple solution.